# Getting access of Juyterhub single user pods on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have Jupyterhub single server pods running with jupyterlab,some volumes mounts and nsg rules configured inside my aks cluster, Can I somehow use this juyterhub deloyment to run notebooks on VSCode with same environment as in single server and also getting access to those same mounts on VSCode. What should be best method to do this?